# Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy skipping element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap, and have been for a while. I have only today used the scrollspy component and I am having some weird issue with it.
The scrollspy defaults to making the "pricing" link active. There is only one ID with #pricing on it. I have searched and searched for an answer.
Link: http://ibexcore.com/services/web-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect element (using chrome) on the pricing `h1` and hover over the element in the code inspector, you'll notice the `h1` area seems to be covering almost the whole page.

It looks like you've either got some error in your html, or some unusual CSS rules causing it's area to be so large

**EDIT** - on second look, your pricing `h1` looks to be outside of the twitter bootstrap guidelines of

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span#"></div>
  <div class="span#"></div>
</div>
```

yours is like this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span#"></div>
  <div class="span#"></div>
  <h1 id="pricing"></h1>
</div>
```

I'd guess sticking it back into a `<div class="span#">` would fix it

[image]

Comment: Oh dear lord! Cheers for pointing that out. I have changed the h1 ID and class and h1 still takes up the whole page. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try my edit? If you shift the `h1` so that is resides inside the `span10` you have, that should fix it.

Comment: Worked brilliantly thanks. Been pulling my hair out for the past hour or so!